# How to do AND or OR in XPATH on combined divs

Tags: selenium, xpath

I would like to get a DIV based on two conditions in children DIVs.

```
//div//[child::div[text()="Administrator"] and //child::div[text='No card']]
```

But and condition appears to be working on properties of a single element.
Kindly advise how to achieve something like above, using either Xpath or CSSSelector

HTML:

```
<div>
   <div class="src-containers-Quo-SimpleCard-components-styles-index__carHolderRow-" style="transition: s;">
      <h4 class="-shared-react-components1Lsp1">Mr.</h4>
      <div class="src-containers-Quo-SimpleCard-components-styles-index__carDetails--3xMqU">
         <div class="src-containers-Quo-SimpleCard-components-1bGot">bla</div>
         <div class="src-containers-Quo-SimpleCard-components--1bGot">Administrator</div>
         <div><button class="src-containers-Quo-simpleCard-" type="button">Edit</button><button class="src-containers-Quo-SimpleCard-" type="button">Delete</button></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you share HTML sample for the same? Also what do you mean by *"working on properties of a single element"*?

Comment: <div><div class="src-containers-Quo-SimpleCard-components-styles-index__carHolderRow-" style="transition: s;"><h4 class="-shared-react-components1Lsp1">Mr.</h4><div class="src-containers-Quo-SimpleCard-components-styles-index__carDetails--3xMqU"><div class="src-containers-Quo-SimpleCard-components-1bGot">bla</div><div class="src-containers-Quo-SimpleCard-components--1bGot">Administrator</div><div><button class="src-containers-Quo-simpleCard-" type="button">Edit</button><button class="src-containers-Quo-SimpleCard-" type="button">Delete</button></div></div></div></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if you want to select `div` by text values of two child `div` elements, you can do

```
//div[div="Administrator" and div="No card"]
```

Let me know (update your question) if you faced with another issue

P.S. Note that `//div[//child::div[text='No card']]` means something like *return FIRST `div` if there is a `div` with text 'No card' somewhere in DOM*, but not what you expect

Comment: How to achieve this for applying And or Or on the same element? i.e. [div="Administrator" or div="No card"]

Comment: @user2451016 , can you elaborate a little? `[div="Administrator" or div="No card"]` means *return True if at least one child found*. What is your case?

Comment: I would like to do Or/And on the attribute of a given node, this time instead of child

Comment: @user2451016 , do you mean `[@attr="value1" or @attr="value2"]`?